# Content scripts difference between Firefox and Chrome: not able to get API data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm fetching data on Arxiv.org's api with my chrome extension.

The following code works when executed:

- [x] Popup on Chrome
- [x] Content script on Chrome
- [x] Popup on Firefox
- [ ] Content script on Firefox <- why is that, how can I debug?

If it is of any help, `content_script.js` is triggered on https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06146

```js
// content_script.js
$.get(`https://export.arxiv.org/api/query`, { id_list: "1801.06146" })
    .done((data) => {
        console.log("done");
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        console.log("fail");
        console.log({ jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown });
    });
```

The FF failure looks like:

[image: jserror]

```json
// manifest.json
"permissions": [
    "https://arxiv.org/*",
    "https://proceedings.neurips.cc/*",
    "https://openaccess.thecvf.com/*",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "downloads"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://arxiv.org/*",
        "*://*.arxiv-vanity.com/*",
        "*://proceedings.neurips.cc/*",
        "*://openaccess.thecvf.com/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": [
        "src/shared/jquery.min.js",
        "src/shared/utils.min.js",
        "src/content_scripts/content_script.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/content_scripts/downloadButton.css",
        "src/content_scripts/loader.css",
        "src/content_scripts/content_script.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: An image of your error text is not very useful.

Comment: Well sometimes it is, you can see `errorThrown: ""` and `textStatus: "error"` and there's nothing in `jqXHR` of interest. If you think there is I'll gladly update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error is not very useful but I figured the problem out: adding `"https://export.arxiv.org/*",` to the manifest's permissions.

For some reason (?) Chrome allows `https://export.arxiv.org/api/...` declaring   `https://arxiv.org/*` but not Firefox